Getting high loss on the model that I created
I can't share the full data on the stack, so I would just share the code below.
I have been trying for the past few days on this data but it seems that the loss is coming around 18000 or 15000 which is to high.  My colleagues told me to use neural network for this data.
model = Sequential([
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=80)

Epoch 1/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 78ms/step - loss: 242343.5312 - mae: 465.7755
Epoch 2/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 20ms/step - loss: 243483.7969 - mae: 468.0649
Epoch 3/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 29ms/step - loss: 246071.8281 - mae: 468.4903
Epoch 4/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 20ms/step - loss: 250888.7188 - mae: 476.0695
Epoch 5/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 15ms/step - loss: 242264.2188 - mae: 465.4283
Epoch 6/100
3/3 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 16ms/step - loss: 242441.9062 - mae: 464.7845

How to get this loss as low as possible?
Here is an example of my dataset.

There is no input layer in your sequential model: layers.Input. Please have a look here: https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/

I have added the input part but there is still no improvement

Post a minimal reproducible example including a sample dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I have added a sample of my data

Does your target contain negative values? If yes, removing activation='relu' from the last layer may definately help.

There is still no improvement

Hi, I have reviewed your code. Since the issue is that the loss value is not
decreasing, I recommend you to increase the number of neurons in the model
and applying optimization techniques using Keras Tuner this will help to
improve the model performance
